# nginx and asterisk server_name?

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to proxy all traffic to a certain server *unless* the domain is something different?

Basically a `*` for the `server_name` property?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foo.com
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *
}
```

Or, is there a way to set a "default" server, and then it would use it if none of the other specific server configs match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Valery Viktorovsky's answer says, you can't use a * for `server_name`. You can designate a `server` block as the "default" to receive all requests which don't match any others. See [this post](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/07/nginx-primer/) for an explanation. It would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name wontmatch.com; # but it doesn't matter
}
```

See [the docs for `server_name`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) for more.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use * for `server_name`. From the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> A wildcard name may contain an asterisk only on the name’s start or end, and only on a dot border.

However, you can use a regular expression:

```
server {
    server_name   ~^(www\.)?(.+)$;

    location / {
        root   /sites/$2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it $2 and not $1?

Comment: That appears to be a typo: it should be $1.

Comment: $2 is correct, it is the second group that you want

Comment: How would I achieve this for a specific domain since I have other domains on the same server?

Answer (score 3):

FYI, for those like me who were looking for something a little different, the following configuration will listen and respond to all port 80 request whether you use IP or URL (AKA everything):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
...
}
```

Taken from: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

> In catch-all server examples the strange name “_” can be seen:
>
> server {
>       listen       80  default_server;
>       server_name  _;
>       return       444; } There is nothing special about this name,...

You will get errors on `sudo service nginx restart` or `... start` while `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` symbolic link is still active since it uses the same matching pattern. Simply remove that link and everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update.. according to the docs the wildcards do work now: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html